# How to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, onsaveinstancestate

What could be causing this exception?

> E/AndroidRuntime(16901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901): Process: com.borqs.karbonn.music, PID: 16901
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1323)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1341)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:609)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:587)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at com.borqs.music.MusicHubMainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MusicHubMainActivity.java:1167)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$1.onItemSelected(ActionBarView.java:148)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:893)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:861)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)^M
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16901):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is my onSave instance code

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    saveInstance =true;
    if (state == null)
    {
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        MediaPlaybackFragment fragment = new MediaPlaybackFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        state.putInt("position", mPostion);
        selectedTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        state.putInt("tabhostselected", selectedTab);
        state.putBoolean("isSaveInstance", saveInstance);
        // state.putBoolean("draweropened", mDrawergarment.isDrawerOpened());
    }
}
```

This is my on navigation code

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
    Fragment newFragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    newFragment = new MediaPlaybackFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment, "Music");
    ft.commit();
}

Any help would be much appreciated, if you need more information please ask.
```

Comment: And mention line MusicHubMainActivity.java:1167 in it.

Comment: what API level you are using?

Comment: [This might be useful](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)?

Comment: line no 1167 : ft.commit();

Comment: @ken Y-N the link which is pasted deals with support library v4 but iam not using any v4 libraries

Comment: @zzz It may still valid, though. Please post your code for `com.borqs.music.MusicHubMainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected` at least.

Comment: Please use 'Ctrl + K' with your code. This way the code cannot be properly read.

Comment: Please help me in finding the proper solution struggling from 3 days

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

to

```
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Probably you commit your transaction somewhere else in your code - you should use commitAllowingStateLoss() there aswell. But i would recommend you to rewrite your code to avoid commit after onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: @ localhost but as per documentation Like commit() but allows the commit to be executed after an activity's state is saved. This is dangerous because the commit can be lost if the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so this should only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state to change unexpectedly on the user.

Comment: @ localhost what do u say for this

Comment: @zzz, sorry, but i didn't get your question:)

Comment: @ localhost as per documentation of "commitAllowingStateLoss()" it looks like we cant use this "commitAllowingStateLoss" there is chance of loosing the commit

Comment: @zzz, u won't loose a commit, you could loose state (meaning you could not operate backstack for example), but transaction will be commited and fragments will be replaced or added/deleted. Just try it out.